# Wildcards in a PowerShell findstr string

Tags: powershell, wildcard, findstr

I'm using `findstr` to look for a particular configuration setting in some files. In this case, I am looking for lines that begin with the string `*=`, but could also be `* =` or `*     =` etc. (any amount of blank spaces between the asterisk and equal sign).

So far I have tried:

```
findstr /s /i /b "*\*=" .\config.ini
findstr /s /i /b "*.*=" .\config.ini
findstr /s /i /b "*`*=" .\config.ini
```

Basically, any escape character I could find in the PowerShell documentation, without success.

Comment: This site is for programming related questions. Questions about use of OS command line tools or commands such as findstr belong on [su] instead. Your question has nothing to do with Powershell, as it is asking strictly about findstr. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: search powershell regex, regex101.com, and follow advice in prev comment.

Comment: You might want to look into doing this in a PowerShell way. For instance by using `Get-Content` and `-match`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex style when searching for patterns in your ini files.

I used this test config.ini:

```
*=abc
* = cde
**=avc
a=b
c = d
e =
```

And with this command I get the lines you described in your question:

```
findstr /R /C:"^\*[ ]*=.*" config.ini
```

The result is:

```
*=abc
* = cde
```

Here a description of the regex: `^` means the beginning of the line. Then you ask for a `*`. You have to escape it, so you have to use `\*`. After that, there can be any number of spaces, so you have put it into a regex class, i.e. `[ ]*` (`[<space>]*`). After the spaces, there is an equal sign `=` and after the equal sign, there can be any other character, so `.*`.